# Why does the \newhelp toks uses a \csname construct in its definition?

Tags: tex-core

In LaTeX2e there are still remnants of Plain TeX macros. One such macro is `\newhelp`, which is defined as:

`\def\newhelp#1#2{\newtoks#1#1\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}}`

This is not used anywhere in "source2e", but still used in some packages for example "doc".

Why does the macro place `#2` within a `\csname` construct? What are the advantages? I remember reading somewhere that this saves memory. How does it save memory?

Comment: this is explained in the texbook, it saved a few bytes that were worth saving in 1982

Comment: it saves memory as `\this-is-help` is a single token and the name is a string in the string pool, so a byte per character, but `{this is help}` is 12 tokens which have extra baggage of catcodes etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. But wouldn't the storing in the string pool consume an equivalent amount of memory slots?

Comment: No because that really is a string whereas a list of tokens has to store the catcode as well as charcode of each token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The texbook says

```
A ^|\newhelp| macro has been provided to aid in creating home-made help
texts: You can say, e.g., |\newhelp\helpout{This is a help message.}|, and
then give the command `^|\errhelp||=\helpout|' just before issuing an
^|\errmessage|. This method of creating help texts makes efficient
use of \TeX's ^{memory}, because it puts the text into a control sequence
name where it doesn't take up space that is needed for tokens.
```

That is: it saves memory as `\this-is-help` is a single token and the name is a string in the string pool, so a byte per character, but `{this is help}` is 12 tokens which have extra baggage of catcodes etc.